# How to extract a specific text from an image

Tags: java, image, text, ocr, tesseract

Im trying to process something like a business card to get the contact details out of it. My application is java based and i was trying to use tesseract/OCR but they are c++ friendly. Any suggestions on how i could get this to work ?

I have something like :

```
Tesseract tesseractInstance = Tesseract.getInstance();

try
{
    System.out.println(instance.doOCR(image));
}
catch (TesseractException e)
{
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

but this doesnt look for a specific text.

Comment: What specific string are you looking for?

Comment: I would think that you would need to grab each line of text individually, but I could be wrong. What does the library's documentation tell you? That's where I'd start.

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong, still, there must be ways to improve the output quality of this utility, and likely the information on how to do this will be contained within its documentation.

Comment: Im looking to get the name out of the image of the card.